# How can I change data array in DataTables after initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table, which gets dataform Javascript array. After the array gets changed, I want to change the data shown in the table without recreating it again.
I start the table with

```
$('#table').dataTable( {
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "data": dataArray,
                    "columns": [
                        { "title": "....
```

Later on I will add one more record to dataArray, but want to preserve all the sorting, filters,...
How do I redraw table with new contents of the dataArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to reload the data to your datatable
2. You need to redraw the table

You need to put all this code in your [`fnInitComplete`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks) function.

Like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
      alert( 'DataTables has finished its initialisation.' );
      if(...){
        //load the new array
        oSettings.aoData = newArray;          
        //redraw the table
        $(this).fnDraw();
      }
    }
  } );
} )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to add a new Row to your table you can take advantage of the add row API

```
  var table  = $("#table").DataTable();
  t.row.add( [
            "col 1 value" ,
            "col 2 value",
            ...
            "col 5 value"
        ] ).draw();
```

http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html